# Drag and Drop help, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I am not sure whats wrong with my Drag and Drop functions. The debugger keeps saying this:
"execute 'setData' on 'DataTransfer': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present".

I am unsure how to fix it. Here is the code:

```js
/* Drag */
function start(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
} 
/* Drop */
function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

function dropper(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = event.dataTransfer.setData("text");
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Comment: Well you are obviously missing a parameter in this line `var data = event.dataTransfer.setData("text");` Have you tried adding in some actual data? Or null if you want to pass nothing?

Comment: He might rather mean `getData("text")` at that place

Comment: @pkeuter I put the 'getData("text")'  part in my code becasue in all of the examples I saw they always had that part within their code. I'm honestly not sure what '("text")' means. The drag portion works its just the drop that I am having trouble with.

Comment: I meant the same piece of code in the dropper section. It could (and probably does) mean (like @Thomas said) that you want getData instead of setData there.

Comment: @pkeuter so I changed it and now it says:                                             "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."                                                                     Oh and thank you for the help so far.